# [QT 5.7.1]QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Tags: qt

1. My work environment is:
   VS2013 with QT 5.7.1
2. When I create the object of QVideoWidget, the Application exit  automatically.
   Than I will find that "QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget" in VS2013's output dialog.

3.My Code is following, could somebody give me some suggestions?

```
    #include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
    #include <QtMultimediaWidgets/qvideowidget.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);

        QVideoWidget *videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
        videoWidget->show();

        return a.exec();
    }
```

Comment: Please paste your `.pro` file. Have you added `QT += widgets multimediawidgets`? if you are linking against Qt widgets module and Qt multimedia widgets module correctly, you shouldn't include `Qtmodule/class.h`, You just need to `#include <QApplication>`, `#include <QVideoWidget>`

Comment: Did you try to Rebuild your project? Didn't you forget to install [Qt Visual Studio Add-in](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2)? Is your Qt version compatible with msvc 2013 compiler? If everything is ok, it looks like one of the Visual Studio 2013 problems with native c++

Comment: @Mike I am using VS2013 not QT Creator,so it is not need to configure the .pro file

Comment: @VladimirBershov I have install QT Visual Studio Add-in.The add-in is qt-vs-tools-msvc2013-2.0.0.vsix. I can compile my program the base QDialog  program and it  run correctly, but when i use the QVideoWidget  the program will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have found the resolution to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am so sorry to ask this stupid question.

1. Reson

The resaon cause this is that my vs2013 work environment is debug,but i add the release library in it.

2. Solution
   [Properties]->[Linker]->[input]  add Qt5MultimediaWidgetsd.lib( not Qt5MultimediaWidgets.lib)